# I run blender 2.82a I get a blank screen

Tags: startup-file

I am using Windows 8 on a 64 bit I just finnished downlaoding blender 2.82 the latest version and installed it.

I run blender I get the c:prompt screen for a millisecond and then the software opens and just a blank grey screen.

AMD Radeon HD 7601M Driver Version 13.151.0.0 Driver Model WDDM 1.3

Any fixes?

---

I am not sure if this is the information you're looking for.

AMD Radeon HD 7601M
Driver Version 13.151.0.0
Driver Model WDDM 1.3

I sincerely apreciate your help

Comment: Check if you system fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x and update your graphics driver.

Comment: Yes it does fulfill the requirements, and the drivers are uptodate, still, nothing!

Comment: What is your GPU and graphics driver version?

Comment: The AMD Radeon HD 7610M has the TeraScale 2 architecture and doesn't fulfill the minimum requirements. Blender 2.8x needs GCN first generation or later.

Comment: Are there solutions out there?

Comment: Either using an older version of Blender that supports your hardware or upgrading your graphics card. Although given that it's a mobile card, you're likely using a laptop which makes this difficult.

Comment: thanks a million. I will use the older version.